# Flutter not applying changes on full restart

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am running a flutter application which seems to discard all the changes I made to an app when I stop the application and restart it but if I restart it or hot reload it everything appears. can someone please elaborate on this issue

Comment: Try `flutter clean`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you expect the changes you've made with hot reload / hot restart to persist past the lifetime of the application. Changes made via hot reload don't persist as you're effectively live-patching your application at runtime, so when you re-run the application you're starting from the original code that was there the last time you installed the application.

If you want changes to persist, even after the application closes, you'll need to re-run `flutter run` with all the changes you want already saved or build a binary to install manually.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going back from the app , all the hot reloads that you have done will be undone and it'll return to the previous state.So everytime you want to go out of app click the red stop button so that it'll save the changes of hot reload

Answer (score -1):

Hot reload have some limitation like:

```
1. If you are getting compilation error
2. Added new Classes for UI and other modules.
3. Change state from stateless to stageful or vice versa
```

above are basic think which do not cover in hot reload.

Hot reload is basically to do minor changes in existing UI and debugging and minor changes in business logic.